# wxpython: How to change TreeListCtrl headers background color?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

wxpython: How to change TreeListCtrl headers background color?

See picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeListCtrl does not support that option as far as I can tell. While it appears to be a custom widget, it is also a wrapped C++ widget, so the ability to change its behavior easily is difficult.

Fortunately there is the HyperTreeList, which is a pure Python implementation of basically the same widget. It provides a custom renderer that you can use to change the column colors with. You can see an example in the wxPython demo package.